# LaunchScreen image for all iPhone screen ratio

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode10, launch-screen

I am stuck with a minor problem (which according to our testers is an issue), that is, the image provided for `LaunchScreen` gets cropped in **`iPhone X,*`** models.

I have been trying to render the image itself on storyboard from Attributes Inspector but it is of no use. Since `coding` isn't allowed for LaunchScreen, I can't change the UIImageView properties programmatically.

I have set the `contentMode` for the UIImageView to `scaleAspectFill`. And hence it gets cropped.

Is there any way to fit the image *corner to corner* for each iPhone model on `LaunchScreen`?

iPhone 6 displays the image perfectly but it's not a good thing for the iPhone XR screenshot provided here.

Please help!

[image: iPhone 6]

[image: iPhone XR]

Comment: Are you following safe are layout guide properly? If not then please check for safe are layout system also try changing the content mode of the `UIImageView` once to fit to check the difference inn another device.

Comment: @onCompletion Hi! I deliberately have fit the bottomAnchor of the imageView to SuperView so that it does not leave a white space under the safe layout margin. And ridiculously this crop problem occurs only for iPhone XR. Check the top left and right corners. The balloons have been cropped for iPhone XR screen.

Comment: Please add 1125 × 2436 size image for iPhone X models.

Comment: @user2931321 Hi! How do I actually add different images for pre-iPhone X and iPhone X models? Can it be done?

Comment: @KoushikMudi What is your image's resolutions? Please provide proper sizes for 1x, 2x and 3x.

Comment: @KoushikMudi yes, you can add. Check for iPhone X and set appropriate image to UIImageview.

Comment: @onCompletion 1x - 750x1,334, 2x - 1,242x2,208, 3x - 1,125x2,436

Comment: @user2931321 Please tell me where I should navigate. The properties for the image in Assets, or the LaunchScreen storyboard or somewhere else?

Comment: If you are using a launch storyboard then you will need to ensure that there is sufficient area around your image so that detail isn't lost due to the cropping/scaling that will occur on different screen sizes.  The alternative is to use different images, rendered specifically for each device type, in a launch asset catalog rather than using a launch storyboard.  This is more time consuming as you will need to make multiple different images but it gives greater control over the image appearance.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you! I'm going to try it now.

Comment: @user2931321 In Assets, `App Icons & Launch Images`

Comment: I just found that. Thanks a lot for your help! @user2931321

Comment: @KoushikMudi good.. please upvote my comment.